# Php print screen in html tag

Tags: php, html

```
<p class="para" style="line-height:1.2em;font-size:0.8em;height:70px;">
            <?php echo $urun[$i]["icerik"]; ?>
</p>
```

I tried to print `$urun[$i]["icerik"];` in `<p></p>` tags but it is printed under this paragraph tags.

Output:

```
<p class="para" style="line-height:1.2em;font-size:0.8em;height:70px;">
            </p>
<p>·LED Nokta Aydınlatma ile keskin , yüksek çözünür..</p>
```

I am using CKEditor to set the "icerik". So it is saved in mysql with html tags. But i don' t know, why its writed under the `<p>`tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't looking at the output from PHP. The browser has parsed the HTML source into a DOM. You are looking at it in a DOM inspector which converts it back to HTML (after repair and normalisation).

You cannot have a paragraph inside another paragraph.

The `<p>` inside your variable implicitly terminates the `<p class="para" style="line-height:1.2em;font-size:0.8em;height:70px;">`.

Comment: so, how can i replace all <p> tags in icerik with php?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php